# What is the preterite of modals?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense, verb-forms

What is it that is called the preterite of modals and How are the preterites of modal verbs used ? Explain with more examples of each preterite of a modal and also give the meanings of the sentences.

Comment: Your questions are more like the ones asked in English test papers..

Comment: It may be asked. But it is difficult question for me because i am poor in English

Comment: Your second question, about how these forms are used, is far too broad to be answered within the scope of an ordinary StackExchange answer. All of these forms are among the 200 most-used words in the language; their use is very complex and quirky. [Entire books](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=modals+English) have been written on the subject. There are more than 500 questions here explicitly tagged with [tag:modal-verbs], and at least as many more which involve the use of modals.

Comment: You said their use is complex, but how can i understand them, suggest me, Which book is written in this subject, could you please suggest me, or give me site link

Comment: You could start with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs).

Answer (score 2):

*Preterite* (not "pretarite") is an alternative term for the *past-tense form* of a verb, so the preterites of modals are the past-tense forms of the modal verbs *can, may, shall* and *will*:

```
 BASE FORM            PRETERITE
 can                  could
 may                  might
 shall                should
 will                 would
```

The modal verb *must* has no distinct preterite form—in fact, it **is** a preterite form whose base form, *mote*, fell out of use 500 years ago.

Comment: Why use of preterite is complex and quirky?

Comment: @yubrajsharma 1) Because the preterite itself does not always express *tense* (time reference): it is also used to express *modality* (actual or logical factuality and probability) and *courtesy* (polite non-demand or obliqueness). 2) Because the modal verbs have evolved many different uses over the thousand-plus-year history of the language, and are still evolving new uses. Some of these uses have mostly disappeared, but have left "fossils" behind in certain fixed phrases and contexts.

Comment: How to master in such a complex subject ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma Formal grammars can protect you from basic mistakes, but like everything else in language study, it's largely a matter of practice: extensive reading and conversation, becoming familiar with actual usage.

Comment: Could=ability in past, possibility in present, suggestion,request
would=conditional, imaginary,request, typical action, uncertainity
 Am i right here?

Comment: @yubrajsharma It's a start.